# Having screens for multiple resolution in Qt

Tags: qt

I am creating a UI in Qt. I have to create screens that fit for three resolutions. Right now what I have done for two resolutions is I have created a base screen and based on resolution I have hard coded the values that need to be set for different grid layouts that I have used.

I would like to know if there is any better way of doing this. Is there any way I can have two UI with same look but different resolution and then make 'this' refer to a particular Ui at start up.

Thank You.

Comment: Use Layouts and define ratios for each cell, this way they will stretch/shrink for every resolution

Comment: I have used them. But the problem is to fit in a specific resolution I have set some specific values for the parameters. Also the buttons have different minimum and maximum values for different resolution. UI goes out of boundary when I change the resolution of screen.

Comment: You may use QML to create resolution-independend GUI.

Comment: You can always get the maximum available space from QDesktopWidget. For detecting resizing on resolution change you will have to connect to the QDesktopWidget resize(screen) signal.

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem by using the QUiLoader which allows for selecting different UI at run time based on requirement. Though a bit lengthy it served my purpose. Hope this is helpful.

Use the following link for example

[Run Time Processing](http://qt.developpez.com/doc/4.6/designer-using-a-ui-file/)

[TextFinder Example](http://qt.developpez.com/doc/4.6/uitools-textfinder/)

For Qt 5.0 the changes are 
In .pro file 
Instead of CONFIG += uitool

use `Qt += uitool

Thank You :)